# Cannot style mat-tab without ::ng-deep and !important

Tags: html, css, angular, element

I have some components which use the mat-tab elements in the HTML. When trying to style these elements in the CSS, I am only able to style them using `::ng-deep .mat-tab-label {}` for example, and putting `!important` next to at least one of the style changes. I do not want to leave this in the application long-term, especially after reading [this](https://hackernoon.com/the-new-angular-ng-deep-and-the-shadow-piercing-combinators-deep-and-drop-4b088dbe459) article.

Here is how it breaks down looking at the elements in developer tools:

```
<mat-card class="mat-card">
  <mat-tab-group class="mat-tab-group mat-primary">
    <mat-tab-header class="mat-tab-header">
      <div class="mat-tab-header-pagination mat-tab-header-pagination-before mat-elevation-z4 mat-ripple mat-tab-header-pagination-disabled>
      <div class="mat-tab-label-container">
        <div class="mat-tab-list">
          <div class="mat-tab-labels">
            <div class="mat-tab-label mat-ripple mat-tab-label-active ng-star-inserted">
            <mat-ink-bar class="mat-ink-bar">
```

What can I do in order to style these elements without using `::ng-deep` and `!important` in the CSS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What can I do in order to style these elements without using ::ng-deep
>   and !important in the CSS?

In this case the solution that you can do is to use **Selector specificity** and then put your style in the root style /src/styles.css 
(NOTE: that don't put it in the components styleUrls your style will not work)

```
/* label style */
.mat-tab-label{
  background: green;
  color:white;
}
/* focus style */
.mat-tab-group.mat-primary .mat-tab-label:not(.mat-tab-disabled):focus, .mat-tab-group.mat-primary .mat-tab-link:not(.mat-tab-disabled):focus, .mat-tab-nav-bar.mat-primary .mat-tab-label:not(.mat-tab-disabled):focus, .mat-tab-nav-bar.mat-primary .mat-tab-link:not(.mat-tab-disabled):focus{
  background: red;
}
/* ink bar style */
.mat-tab-group.mat-primary .mat-ink-bar, .mat-tab-nav-bar.mat-primary .mat-ink-bar{
  background: yellow;
  height: 10px;
}
```

To see the live sample code please see this link -
 https://stackblitz.com/edit/dmgrave-ng-so-anser-tabs-style?file=styles.css

Hope this helps.

Comment: The link states that /deep/ is deprecated, along with ::ng-deep, which is the reason for my original question. I understand it works, but it is not recommended.

Comment: @tb517 I see, please see my updated answer and hope it helps.